# Issue with new design: Visited links are nearly indistinguishable in color from regular text

Tags: feature-request, bug, design

I love the new site design, but to me the links, particularly **visited** ones, are not different enough in color from regular text. In the example below the text 'this post' is a visited link:

[image]

Comment: +1. I agree - I was going to post something about this, too, and spotted your meta post about it.

Comment: +1 Also keep in mind, when dealing with colors and UX, that there are *colorblind* people. About 8% of the world's male population cannot distinguish between a whole variety of colors that graphic designers think look different from each other.

Comment: So, who has the power to actually fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Edit 7/18/2015: I think this is now complete with [the changes announced here](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/10997).  It looks much better to me!

Edit 3/3/2015: I've asked about this issue [on meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250552/232449).

---

This still hasn't been addressed, even though I've asked [a duplicate question about it](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1966/10997). And it's not just in the comments, but in the questions and answers that visited links are very difficult to see.

In a recent post of mine on this site, here is what some text with visited links looks like:

**Personal Finance & Money:**

[image: a post with visited links from Personal Finance & Money]

There are two visited links in there; the color of these links is #3a79a6.

With a beta site design, the visited links are color #4e82c2, which is brighter and much easier to see:

**Sports:**

[image: a post with visited links from Sports]

Both sites have a white background*, so I'm not sure why the colors of the links would be different.

Please change the design colors to make the links easier to see.

---

<sub>*Actually, Money has a pure white background (#ffffff) and Sports has an almost white background (#fdfdfd), but close enough.</sub>