# In comments, not enough contrast between regular text and links

Tags: feature-request

I recently [posted a comment](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/29922/can-i-file-taxes-in-the-state-where-i-own-a-home-even-if-i-dont-live-there#comment45220_29922) to a question with a link, and I noticed that it is very difficult to tell that there is a link there.  The color of the text and the color of the link are very hard to distinguish in a comment.

Here is a screenshot of what I'm talking about:

[image]

On my monitor at least, it is very hard to distinguish.

Looking at the CSS, the regular text appears to be at #444444 and the link text, when not hovered, is at #3A79A6.

Comment: http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/1932/issue-with-new-design-visited-links-are-nearly-indistinguishable-in-color-from?rq=1 Yup.  @Jin - is this being addressed?

Comment: Agree that links are not terribly apparent.  [Related complaint on visited link color](http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/1932/issue-with-new-design-visited-links-are-nearly-indistinguishable-in-color-from).