# Updates to the site

Tags: discussion, design

You may have noticed some updates to the design lately, they are part of a SE network-wide update to a new base css framework.

The updates allow us to:

- Have sharper / more beautiful design on retina displays
- Fix layout bugs
- More easily add new features to all of our sites in the future

> **But more importantly, it gives you access [to the new profile](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/current)!**

If you see any bugs please let us know in the form of answers (to this post) that illustrate one particular thing at a time.

Thanks!

Comment: Great! Looking forward to the new profile becoming available here.

Comment: While we're at it, could we get "delete answer" added to the Android app?

Comment: I'm looking forward to the profile update.  I'll also be looking for a fix to [this design bug](http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/q/1932/10997).  Finally, I'm a Firefox user, and I'm hoping I don't see the [same issue that I saw on DIY](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/q/1047/18557) after that site was updated.

Comment: @kes how is it related?

Comment: @nicael: jest in the general category of "if you see any bugs" and "prioritizing features" -- though right now my first priority over either of these would be to make the app stable again.

Comment: Love it, Stéphane!